# Is there a way to write regex to avoid matching a # inside a string

Tags: python, regex

I am writing Syntax Highlighting for Python, and I want to make comments only be highlighted as comments if they are not included in strings.
What is currently happening:

```py
# this line will be matched
x = '# this line is matched from `#` onwards'
```

however I want it to only select the line to be matched if there are no `'` or `"` surrounding the `#`.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXJ6P.png)
my current regex is as follows: `#[^\n]*` which selects a `#` and everything after, but I don't know how to make it check for surrounding `'` first

Comment: You already know how to test to see if `\n` is not in the string; how is this different?

Comment: Regex isn't the best option for writing a syntax highlighter; problems like this will keep tripping you up. You need to look at writing a lexer / parser.

Comment: Actually just use ast.parse if the syntax highlighter is also in Python; still, it's true that most editor etc. nowadays only support regex for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

To check if something is surrounded you can use the lookbehind and lookahead :

```
pattern = (?<=['|\"]).*#.*(?=['|\"])
```

(?<) this is for a lookbehind, addind a "!" will make it negative. Basically you're checking if there is not a specific character before.

(?) Same applies to this except this look after and not before

This pattern will match when the '#' is surrounded by this ' or this "